# How to catch alexa´s data output in text?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

We are currently working on a school project for which we would need to display the alexa output data in a program. For example when you ask alexa for the weather, our program would need to display something like 24° Celsius with a sun in the background. 
The displaying isn´t the problem, but we can´t quite find out how we can get hold of the temperature for example. Since alexa´s answers are also displayed in the alexa app we figured there is some kind of way to get hold of them and we also saw that it is possible in other peoples projects.
We read the docs but they only suggest creating a personal skill and don´t discuss how to obtain the results of an existing skill.

We just wanted to know if it is possible to do that, any tips are greatly appreciated. Sorry for the noob question but we are fairly new to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as you already wrote it yourself, it is impossible to grab speech from other skills, except the ones that you code yourself. I haven't heard anything about making speech public, but you can still keep an eye on [alexa blog](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/) or try posting this as a feature request in [alexa uservoice](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote) webspace.

Answer (score -1):

Well i recommend to take a look at [outputSpeech.ssml](https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html)

This how i do for get the last response

```
 let lastReprompt = response.reprompt.outputSpeech.ssml;
 lastReprompt = lastReprompt.replace('<speak>', '');
 lastReprompt = lastReprompt.replace('</speak>', '');
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: This would work in a skill that user built himself, but this thread author is asking how to get text from already built skills or built in features, which is unfortunately impossible at the moment.